# What happen if scanf don't get enough characters from the standard input?

Tags: c

I know that the scanf function read the characters from standard input and it interpret them using the conversions specifications but what it will happen if there is some missing characters in the input stream ? it freeze until getting the next characters that it need to or it just ends ? For exemple :
the scanf call : 
scanf ( " %d  %d ", arg1, arg2) ;
the input stream : 14

Sorry for any mistakes in vocabulary. english is'nt my mother tong

Comment: It's a synchronous function, it will not return until it reads everything you to told it to read or there is some kind of error on the input stream.

Comment: @jwdonahue you can forcefully stop it by inputting an `EOF`

Comment: @user12986714 Yup, an error on the input stream.

Comment: how it can be possible to stop scanf forcefully , it is part of the standard library ?

Comment: No, such things about "forcefully stop it by inputting an EOF" are an implementation of the user interface, not C.  `stdin`  receives a signal to indicate end-of-file (or input error) by various implementation specific means.  Some call this "inputting an EOF".

Answer (score 2):

> What happen if `scanf` don't get enough characters from the standard input?

In *general*, scanning stops and `scanf()` returns the number of successful matching format specifiers.  Unmatched input characters remains in `stdin`.  The later specifiers' corresponding pointers' data are unchanged.

Yet there are many details - the above and below are over-simplifications.

---

`scanf()` stops under various conditions:

1) **The happy path** The format is fully satisfied.   There is nothing more to the *format* string.

2) Input does not match the specifier anymore.  Specifiers like `"%d"`, `"%f"`, `"%99[^\n]"`, `"%99s"` consume input until some character that does not meet the specifiers needs - that character(s) is put back in the stream.  If insufficient characters were read, scanning stops and the number of successful matching format specifiers is returned.  If enough were read, scanning continues to the next part of the format.  (`"%n"` is special - not addressed here).

```
int retval = sscanf("1abc", "%d", &i);  // stop at 'a', return 1
int retval = sscanf("+1-", "%d%d", &i);  // stop at '-', return 1
```

2) Input does not match a fixed character except white-space, scanning stops.  Returning the number of successful matching format specifiers.

```
int retval = sscanf("1abc", "%da", &i);  // stop at 'b', return 1
```

3) End-of-file occurs.  `scanf()`returns the number of successful matched format specifiers.

4) Input error (rare).  E.g. some internal mis-communication or trying to read from `stdout`.  All pointers' data values are indeterminate.  Return `EOF`.

5) Nothing matched, return `EOF`.

---

```
scanf ( " %d %d ", arg1, arg2) ;
```

With input `"14"` - end-of-file,

1) The first `" "` scans zero or more white-space.  Never fails, scanning continues.

2) The first `"%d"` scans zero or more white-space then scans for numeric input consuming the `"14"`.  `*arg1` is set to 14.

3a) End-of-file occurs.  `*arg2` unchanged.  `scanf()` return 1.

---

With input `"14\n"` like above until 3a above.

3b) The 2nd `" "` scans zero or more white-space. It consumes `'\n'` and waits until a non-white-space  is detected or end-of-file.  `scanf()` is still processing and has not yet returned.

Comment: Nice answer.  What about input stream buffering from the source?

Comment: @jwdonahue Same applies as with a keyboard.  Buffering simple makes data available to `scanf()` in chunks.  The temporal aspects of data changes, not the sequence.

Comment: Thank you, you have clarified many things about how scanf works and i think we can conclude that scanf has two different behaviors depending on which character is obtained in the end of the stream : - if the last thing obtained from the stream is EOF it will ends and return the number of seccessfully treated specifications. - if the last thing obtained from the stream is " \n " it will stop there just waiting for more characters from the strem to carry on.

Comment: @RamziBouali Right.  In the second case, the format is not done yet, so no need to return at this time.

Comment: But it's a little bit confusing for me to have EOF in the end of the stream because as we know scanf reads the flow from the standard input  which by default is the keyboard. So how EOF can be in the end of the stream instead of " \n"

Comment: @RamziBouali True the keyboard does not vanish, yet end-of-file to `stdin` can be signaled to the program by various means.  Also consider your code run on a command line with re-directed input.  `RM_program < input.txt`.  Once the file is read by your code, `getchar()` receives `EOF`.  In both cases, the last character before end-of-file may be a non-`'\n'`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the input stream is closed after 14.

The value of `*arg2` will get unchanged.

But `*arg1` will read fine; it will become `14`.

Otherwise:

scanf will just wait until you input another integer. (and if you do not, your program will hang here forever)

Comment: That would be the result if the input stream is closed after the 14, however it seems to me they were asking about what happens when the stream is not closed.  (And it is the value pointed to by arg1 and arg2, not their own values)

Comment: The stream can't be passed to scanf unless  it is closed. isn't it ?

Comment: @Ramzi no. Say you inputed `14 15\n` the stream is not closed (no EOF), but scanf will return successfully.

Comment: However in line buffer mode (in tty), stream is not passed until one hits enter. One can turn off line buffer mode and get into raw mode using `stty`

Answer (score 1):

Given that you only input 14, scanf will wait for the remaining input specified in your format string or there is an input error, such as unexpected input or the input stream is closed.

Comment: @RamziBouali, glad to help, but I think Chux has a more complete answer.  Just keep in mind that when you're trying to do synchronous (blocking) reads from an asynchronous channel, you should not assume that output from the device or process on the other end, is input on your end.  If you had two threads, one reading the channel and the other watching *arg1, it's possible you would never see a value change.

Comment: can you explain this issue in more details please ?

Comment: You are coding to an interface.  There's lots of implementation details that happen, in the library your calling into, the operating system drivers and the hardware devices they support.  C streams are an abstraction that reduces communications to a fairly expansive common denominator, but it's still limited, compared to the range of I/O devices and intervening firm/soft-ware.  There are literally thousands of points at which might occur when performing I/O.  Until the I/O interface you called, returns a status, you really can't make any assumptions about its side effects (ie variable states)

Comment: On most desktop systems and servers, very few things happen serially.  Even when you're calling a synchronous interface in C, it is generally interacting with multiple asynchronous processes.  The keyboard is a good case in point.  If the system waited for program to call for input before scanning the keyboard, most of what we type would never be seen.  So there are threads in your OS kernel and interrupt handlers that buffer asynchronous events so that when your program gets around to reading input, there can be something waiting.  In the case where their isn't, your program blocks.

Comment: So, you're coding to an interface.  The docs for that interface do not say anything about the state of your output variables prior to the function returning a status.  You cannot assume that arg1 gets anything assigned to it, until after your call to `scanf` returns something that indicates it read something from input.

Comment: I would add that the configurations of some device drivers that you might redirect to stdin, also have timeout values that will fail on a read if there is no input after a specified period of time.  I grew up in the age in the teletypes and even operated a few of them.  Just because somebody types something on one end of the communications link, it is by no means insured to reach its destination.  I have lots of experience with asynchronous <=> synchronous interfaces and have seen them fail in more ways than I can count.